# Select case based upon form option button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form set up with couple parameters. I have set up my form with two option button "Rolling" and "One Time". I would like to set this up as a condition to select which case to use. For Example if "One time" is selected use select case WITHOUT extend ELSE use select case WITH EXTEND. The below code is what I have now not sure if I am doing this condition correctly.

```
If OnetimeOption.value = True Then

    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "BB"

        Case "Week Two"
            iCol = "BC"

        Case "Week Three"
            iCol = "BD"

        Case "Week Four"
            iCol = "BE"

        Case "Week Five"
            iCol = "BF"

        Case "Week Six"
            iCol = "BG"

        Case "One Seven"
            iCol = "BH"

        Case "One Eight"
            iCol = "BI"

        Case "One Nine"
            iCol = "BJ"

        Case "One Ten"
            iCol = "BK"

        Case "One Eleven"
            iCol = "BL"

        Case "One Twelve"
            iCol = "BM"
    End Select

Else



    nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.value

        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "BB"
            nExtend = 12
        Case "Week Two"
            iCol = "BC"
            nExtend = 11
        Case "Week Three"
            iCol = "BD"
            nExtend = 10
        Case "Week Four"
            iCol = "BE"
            nExtend = 9
        Case "Week Five"
            iCol = "BF"
            nExtend = 8
        Case "Week Six"
            iCol = "BG"
            nExtend = 7
        Case "One Seven"
            iCol = "BH"
            nExtend = 6
        Case "One Eight"
            iCol = "BI"
            nExtend = 5
        Case "One Nine"
            iCol = "BJ"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "One Ten"
            iCol = "BK"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "One Eleven"
            iCol = "BL"
            nExtend = 2
        Case "One Twelve"
            iCol = "BM"
            nExtend = 1
    End Select

End If
```

Comment: What value should the variable nExtend take if OnetimeOption.Value is true?  At the moment it is undefined by the code you have shown, which possibly means it is either taking the value of zero (as a default) or the value last set when OnetimeOption.Value wsa not true.  Also, what do you want iCol to be when OnetimeOption.Value is false and MonthComboBox.value is "Week One"?  At the moment you are setting it to "C" but, in a section of code that will never be reached, you then set it to "N".

Comment: @pnuts because I have a debug on line If OnetimeOption.value = True Then

Comment: @pnuts sorry I have figured it out my property names were not matching one was onetime and another onetimeoption. Still appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it differently if both Select Cases used the same set of values.  But they don't.  I would, however, combine cases that have the same result.

```
If OnetimeOption.Value = True Then

    Select Case MonthComboBox.Value
        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "C"
        Case "Week Two"
            iCol = "N"
        Case "Week Three"
            iCol = "O"
        Case "Week 4"
            iCol = "P"
        Case "Week 5", "Week 6", "One Month"
            iCol = "Q"
    End Select

Else
    nExtend = 1   'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.Value
        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "C"
        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "N"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P"
            nExtend = 2
        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q"
    End Select

End If
```